# JQuery - Apply Stylesheet to Iframe (same domain)

Tags: jquery, iframe, stylesheet

I have an iframe on a single page, and I'm loading html (stored in mysql) into the iframe.
I'd like to apply a separate stylesheet to the `iframe`.

Here's what I'm doing so far:

```
<?php 
  $storedhtml = '<strong>Testing</strong><br><br>lots more html text......';
?>

<iframe id="lovely_pages" src="about:blank" style="width:99%;height:700px;" frameBorder="0"></iframe>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#lovely_pages').contents().find('html').html('<?php echo $storedhtml; ?>');

});
</script>
```

Here's the stylesheet I want to apply to the `iframe`:

`<link href="/styles/iframe_only.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

I've tried placing the stylesheet into the `html()` with the `$storedhtml` variable, but that didn't change anything.
Can anyone see what I'm doing incorrect?

Comment: Doesn't look like you have a head, body, or anything else in your iFrame, as you're just inserting a simple string into the documentElement, overwriting everything else. The browser would probably try and fix that, but styles should be in the head, so you either have to insert valid HTML or access the head element that the browser creates to try and fix your stupid mistakes.

Comment: I was just playing around with that, as I noticed there wasn't much inside the `iframe`, other than the simple string.

Answer (score 2):

The following modification below fixed the outcome:

```
<?php 
  $storedhtml = '<strong>Testing</strong><br><br>lots more html text......';
?>

<iframe id="lovely_pages" src="about:blank" style="width:99%;height:700px;" frameBorder="0"></iframe>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#lovely_pages').contents().find('head').html('<link href="/styles/iframe_only.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">');
  $('#lovely_pages').contents().find('body').html('<?php echo $storedhtml; ?>');

});
</script>
```